# Trouble with ImageTextures in OpenGL 4.2

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to write a simple test program to demonstrate the functionality of GLSL 4.2's `ImageLoad` function. So far I have:

- A simple Shader that loads the bottom-left texel from an `image2D` and displays it.
- Some simple vertex code to draw a fullscreen squad
- Other scaffolding code to create a context, compile shaders, etc.

Here's my frag code (vertex is a simple passthrough shader):

```c
#version 420

#include <gtest/SmallImage.h> //NOTE: I have a preprocessor that takes care of includes

layout(binding = SMALL_IMAGE_ONE_BINDING, rgba8) uniform image2D image_one;

smooth in vec2 texture_coords;
out vec4 out_color;

void main(void)
{
  vec4 loaded = imageLoad(image_one, ivec2(0,0));
  vec4;
  out_color = vec4(loaded.r,
               loaded.g,
                   gl_FragCoord.y/1200.0,
                   1);
}
```

Pretty simple, no read room for mishap. The blue channel being proportionate to pixel coordinates lets me know that the quad is being properly rendered even if the `imageLoad` call fails.

Here is the C++ loop I'm using to render to the screen. It binds a texture, writes a single yellow texel, then renders a fullscreen quad. There are two variants: when `MAKE_ONCE` is defined, the texture is generated once, before the loop. If it is not defined, a new texture is generated on each iteration of the loop:

```c
MyTestFun(void)
{
  glm::vec4 yellow = glm::vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); 

#ifdef MAKE_ONCE
  renderer->InitFrame();  //sets current OpenGL context 
  GLuint name = 0;
  glGenTextures(1, &name);   
  renderer->EndFrame();  
#endif

  while(1)
  {     
    renderer->InitFrame();

#ifndef MAKE_ONCE
    GLuint name =0;
    glGenTextures(1, &name);   
#endif

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, name);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 1, 1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT,
                 glm::value_ptr(yellow));

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glBindImageTexture(SMALL_IMAGE_ONE_UNIT, name, 0, false, 0, GL_READ_ONLY,
                       GL_RGBA8);


    renderer->FullscreenQuad(); //shades using the frag shader shown above

    //bind the default texture to the image unit, hopefully freeing ours for editing
    glBindImageTexture(SMALL_IMAGE_ONE_UNIT, 0, 0, false, 0, GL_READ_WRITE,
                       GL_RGBA8);

    renderer->EndFrame();
  }
}
```

When `MAKE_ONCE` is defined, the first frame shows a vertical gradient from white to yellow, but subsequent frames show a vertical gradient from blue to black, indicating that the `IMAGE_LOAD` call is returning 0.0.

When `MAKE_ONCE` is not defined, e.g. the texture is remade on every frame, the program behaves as expected, showing the same white<->yellow gradient on every frame.

What might be causing this behavior? The OpenGL 4.2 specification says that an `imageLoad` call will return black (all zeros) if the image is in an invalid state (p255-266), but none of the validity conditions seem to apply here.

Comment: How about moving the initialization of the texture outside of the loop, so that it is not constantly recreating the texture?

Comment: First frame correct; remaining frames wrong.

Also, the actual code as a glGetError() call after each line, none of which report anything. I have the gl_ARB_Debug_Output extension running, and that doesn't report anything, either. I'm sort of worried this is a driver bug.

Comment: Have you tried it on another vendor's card/driver combination?